# Return calculated custom attribute from Laravel Pivot

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm building a service API and would like to return a calculated date called '*expire_at*' in my JSON response for '*subscriptions*' relation below. The date will be calculated based on knowing '*activated_at*', '*interval*' and '*interval_type*'. This can of course be calculated on the front-end, but I would like to provide this conveniently in my API response. I can't figure out where to put the logic though.

I could put it in the Plan model using the $appends property, but that would only work when requesting plans from a Customer. Putting it in the CustomerController would require looping through each subscription for each customer.

Where should I put the logic of calculating this date for each subscription in the customer result? Are above places my only two options?

**Customer JSON result:** (with 'expire_at' added)

```
{
  id: 4327,
  name: "Test Company",
  created_at: "2014-05-29 21:12:37",
  updated_at: "2014-05-29 21:12:37",
  subscriptions: [
    {
      id: 93754,
      name: "Test standard plan",
      description: "An example subscription plan",
      ...
      created_at: "2014-05-29 21:12:37",
      updated_at: "2014-05-29 21:12:37",
      activated_at: "2014-05-29 00:00:00",
      active: true,
      renewal_active: false,
  //  expire_at: "2014-06-28 00:00:00",
      interval: 1,
      interval_type_name: "Monthly"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Plan model:**

```
class Plan extends Eloquent {

  protected $guarded = array('id');
  protected $hidden = array('pivot');

  public function customers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Customer');
  }

}
```

**Customer model:**

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {

  protected $guarded = array('id');

  public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('User');
  }

  public function subscriptions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Plan')->withPivot('activated_at as activated_at', 'active as active', 'renewal_active as renewal_active');
  }
}
```

**Customer Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
  $customer = Customer::with('subscriptions')->find($id);

  return Response::json($customer);
}
```

Comment: Giving this some additional thought, I think it might be best to calculate the '_expire_at_' date on regular basis (i.e. on events such as payments etc) in my Subscription Controller (not shown above) and actually store/update the date in the database. This will reduce the amount of calculations done each time a customer and/or subscription is being fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the logic to produce the **expire_at** attribute in the pivot table. 
To achieve this you need to create the pivot model with the logic and than tell Laravel how to use it.

**Pivot model:**

```
class Subscription extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'customer_plan'; // point this to your pivot table

    protected $appends = array('expires_at');

    public function getExpiresAtAttribute()
    {
        return 'tomorrow';
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
    }

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Plan');
    }

}
```

Now we tell Laravel that Customer and Plan should use the Subscription model.

**Customer model:**

```
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Subscription');
    }
}
```

**Plan model:**

```
class Plan extends Eloquent
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Subscription');
    }
}
```

The query to fetch the data changes slightly:

```
$customer = Customer::with('subscriptions.plan')->find($id);
return Response::json($customer);
```

Comment: Thanks @maxwilms! However, this is exactly what I already have, except that '_expire_at_' is now a table column being set on subscription creation (i.e. using the attach method - `$customer->subscriptions()->attach(..)`). This way I don't need to calculate the date each time a subscription is being fetched and cron jobs can easily use this value too. Thanks for your time and support!

Comment: Answer marked as Accepted as it is applicable to the initial question. Thanks.